Power BI: distinct count over a dynamic range
Please, advise me how to solve this problem in Power BI:
I need to visualize a distribution of a distinct count from MIN(FromDate) to MAX(ToDate)
I inserted a screenshot to visualize an input and a desired output.
enter image description here
I have created a data range in separate table as CALENDAR(MIN(FromDate) to MAX(ToDate)), but I failed to write an expression for the measure for this two non-related tables.

See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78868609/21688343

you can try to create a column
Column =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[From Data] <= 'date'[Date]
            && 'Table'[To date] >= 'date'[Date]
    )
)


